# How can you safely pass a session variable to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this account balance variable:

```
$_SESSION["bitcoin-balance"] = 0;
```

I need to pass it to a javascript function, which will append the variable in a URL to send to my RESTAPI.

```
function getAccountBalace(username, hash){
//Send to restapi
}
```

How could I do this? Normally, I would just make PHP echo javascript code with the parameters, when the page loads, but I need this function to run when a user clicks a button; and I cannot have the web page to reload.

Comment: Have you tried using ajax?

Comment: *"everything is checked server-side, users cannot call this function to cheat"* - If everything is checked server-side anyway, why do you need this to be a parameter at all? Just look it up server-side at the time of the request.

Comment: This is just an example. Though what I really need is the username and hash from session. The amount and function name do indeed make that statement seem misleading.

Comment: Have you looked into things like [OAuth](https://oauth.net/) or [JWT](https://jwt.io/) for scenarios like this? (Assuming that your REST API is RESTful, as in stateless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<button onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $_SESSION["bitcoin-balance"]; ?>');" />
```